# How to figure out SmartForms is build?

Tags: sapui5

I have a SmartForm that looks as following:

```
<Dialog id="massChangeDialog" title="{i18n>ChangeMaintainanceOrderOperation}" resizable="true" draggable="true" contentWidth="900px"
    contentHeight="700px">
    <content>
        <smartForm:SmartForm id="editOperation" editable="true" entityType="EditOperation">
            <smartForm:Group>
                <smartForm:GroupElement>
                    <smartField:SmartField value="{WorkCenter}" id="idWorkCenter" width="90%" class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"/>
                </smartForm:GroupElement>
            </smartForm:Group>
            <smartForm:Group>
                <smartForm:GroupElement>
                    <smartField:SmartField value="{PersonalNumber}" id="idPersonalNr" width="90%"/>
                </smartForm:GroupElement>
            </smartForm:Group>
            <smartForm:Group>
                <smartForm:GroupElement>
                    <smartField:SmartField value="{ActionDescription}" width="90%" id="idDispatch"/>
                </smartForm:GroupElement>
            </smartForm:Group>
            <smartForm:Group>
                <smartForm:GroupElement>
                    <smartField:SmartField value="{ChangedDate}" id="idDate" width="90%"/>
                </smartForm:GroupElement>
            </smartForm:Group>
            <smartForm:Group>
                <smartForm:GroupElement>
                    <smartField:SmartField value="{ChangedTime}" id="idTime" width="90%" placeholder="{i18n>EnterTime}"/>
                </smartForm:GroupElement>
            </smartForm:Group>
        </smartForm:SmartForm>
    </content>
</Dialog>
```

As you can see, the `SmartForm` sit inside the Dialog. When I call the open method and want to access to `SmartField`, I've got `undefined`.
The code looks like:

First I created an instance of Dialog

```
if (!this.oDialogChangeOperations) {
    // Begin of 0001
    this.oDialogChangeOperations = sap.ui.xmlfragment(this.getView().getId(),
        "rsh.eam.details1.RSH_EAM_DETS1Extension.view.ChangeOperationsCustom", this);
    // End of 0001
    //this.getView().addDependent(this.oDialogChangeOperations);
    this.oDialogChangeOperations.setModel(this.getModel("EditOp"));
    this.oDialogChangeOperations.setModel(this.getView().getModel(), "Origin");
    this.oDialogChangeOperations.setModel(this.getView().getModel("i18n"), "i18n");

    this.byId("MassChange").attachPress(this.onMassChangePressed, this);
} 

this.oDialogChangeOperations.bindElement("/EditOperationSet(1)");
this._openChangeDialog();
```

At the end, I called the function **_openChangeDialog** to open the Dialog:

```
_openChangeDialog: function () {
    if (!this.oDialogChangeOperations.isOpen()) {
        // Pre-setting the filter values
        this.oDialogChangeOperations.open();
        // Deregister this event - no more is it needed
        this.initialWorkCenter = this.byId("idWorkCenter").getBindingContext().getObject().WorkCenter;
        this.intialStatus = this.byId("idDate").getBindingContext().getObject().ActionDescription;
        this.intialPerson = this.byId("idPersonalNr").getBindingContext().getObject().PersonalNumber;
    }
},
```

on the line:

```
this.initialWorkCenter = this.byId("idWorkCenter").getBindingContext().getObject().WorkCenter;
```

I've got `undefined`, because the service does not get loaded yet.
To clarify, what I mean, I set a break point in the `_openChangeDialog` function:

[image]

and you can see, that `SmartForm` did not appear after open the dialog.

After few seconds, `SmartForm` appeared:

[image]

Is there an event, that I can catch, when SmartForm is initialized.